# Openmp what openmp does if the omp for is nested in omp parallel

Tags: multithreading, openmp

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 4;
    int i, j;
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2) private(i)
    for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
    {
        int outer_tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("outside thread id is %d, i = %d.\n", outer_tid,i);

        if (i%2 == 0)
        #pragma omp for
        for (j = 0;j < n;j += 2)
        {
            printf("even, outside thread is %d, inner thread id is %d, i = %d, j = %d.\n", outer_tid , omp_get_thread_num(), i, j);
        }

        else
        #pragma omp for
        for (j = 1;j < n;j += 2)
        {
            printf("odd, outside thread is %d, inner thread id is %d, i = %d, j = %d.\n", outer_tid , omp_get_thread_num(), i, j);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
outside thread id is 0, i = 0.
even, outside thread is 0, inner thread id is 0, i = 0, j = 0.
outside thread id is 1, i = 0.
even, outside thread is 1, inner thread id is 1, i = 0, j = 2.
outside thread id is 0, i = 1.
odd, outside thread is 0, inner thread id is 0, i = 1, j = 1.
outside thread id is 1, i = 1.
odd, outside thread is 1, inner thread id is 1, i = 1, j = 3.
outside thread id is 0, i = 2.
even, outside thread is 0, inner thread id is 0, i = 2, j = 0.
outside thread id is 1, i = 2.
even, outside thread is 1, inner thread id is 1, i = 2, j = 2.
outside thread id is 0, i = 3.
odd, outside thread is 0, inner thread id is 0, i = 3, j = 1.
outside thread id is 1, i = 3.
odd, outside thread is 1, inner thread id is 1, i = 3, j = 3.
```

Clearly,

```
for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
    {
        int outer_tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("outside thread id is %d, i = %d.\n", outer_tid,i);
```

has been executed by both thread 0 and 1. But there is no repeated execution for nested omp for directive. I thought for thread 0, when i = 0, it would parallel the nested for and as well as for thread 1, when i = 0, so there is repetition. But the output proves that I am wrong. What is the strategy for openmp to handle this situation?

Comment: `for` is a worksharing construct. It distributes the iterations of the associated loop among the threads of the enclosing parallel region. Read through [this tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/) for more information.

Comment: I'd suggest @HristoIliev to turn that comment into an answer.